# JavaScript Only last textfield value gets updated

Tags: javascript

I have function which is used to update value in textfield with specific id:

```
function UpdateField(name, val)
{
      var fieldId = "pv-" + name;
      document.getElementById(fieldId).value = val;
}
```

I call it multiple times like this:

```
UpdateField("field1", "somevalue");
UpdateField("field2", "othervalue");
UpdateField("field3", "qwerty");
```

Problem is that first two fields will be blank and only last field (field3) gets correct value. If i remove that third `UpdateField("field3", "qwerty");` call, then field2 will be correct but first one will be blank.

Comment: Then something else is probably wrong; can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Hi, can you show where the functions are called? And add the HTML if possible?

Comment: Those fields are appended to the blank div using element.innerHTML+= '<input id=... Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle of your working code:

https://jsfiddle.net/qzbxa9qa/

```
function UpdateField(name, val) {
    var fieldId = "pv-" + name;
    document.getElementById(fieldId).value = val;
}

UpdateField("field1", "somevalu1e");
UpdateField("field2", "othervalue2");
UpdateField("field3", "qwe3rty");
```

```html
<input id="pv-field1" />
<input id="pv-field2" />
<input id="pv-field3" />
```

Seems that you got a typo in your markup